# Cannot insert json record using axios POST with node.js into postgresql database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, rest, axios

I've tried googling tutorials/examples but I cannot find anything.
Currently, I can insert the JSON record into the first column so I know everything is plugged in, but the JSON is not being broken apart and being put into their respective columns.

This is what I have on my client making the call with a POST

```
async function apiAddRecordToTable(record, table_name) {
   params = record;
   let res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/tables/addrecord/' + table_name, params);
   console.log('add record api called with selected tablename: ' + table_name);
   console.log(res.data);
}
```

This is what I am calling it with (just to test)

```
apiAddRecordToTable({
   "user_id" : "110",
   "user_lon" : "64",
   "user_lat" : "-111",
}, 'user');
```

As for the server, I have a

```
app.post('/tables/addrecord/user', db.addRecordUser);
```

and that calls into this final function:

```
function addRecordUser(request, response) {
   console.log('into final add record user method');
   console.log(request);
   const rec = request.body;
   pool.query('INSERT INTO user_table VALUES ($1)', [rec], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
         throw error
      }
      console.log(results);
      response.status(201).send('Row added')
   })
}
```

The final result in the table looks like

```
USER ID |  USER_LON | USER_LAT
{"user_id":"110","user_lon":"64","user_lat":"-111"}, <null>, <null>
```

I understand that it's most likely inserting the entire record because of the $1 argument but I tried so many variations and searched on how json gets inserted but could not get it to work beyond this. How can I make it look like

```
USER ID |  USER_LON | USER_LAT
110, 64, -111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the `body` to get the parse JSON with `JSON.pare()` method.

And then you can pass the values to the `Parameterized query`. using `$1, $2, $3` place holders.

**Example:**

```
function addRecordUser(request, response) {
    console.log('into final add record user method');
    console.log(request);
    const rec = JSON.parse(request.body);
    let query = 'INSERT INTO user_table VALUES ($1, $2, $3)';
    let values = [rec.user_id, rec.user_lon, rec.user_lat];
    pool.query(query, values, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        console.log(results);
        response.status(201).send('Row added')
    })
}
```

Comment: TY Sohail. But I had to tweak it a bit further to fix it. I am curious though, I was under the impression that if my incoming JSON record is "complete", I do not need to indicate which columns or the number of columns to put the data in? Is this not possible in JavaScript? Or does this have more to do with PostgreSQL ?

Comment: It's not supported in the node drivers for PostgreSQL.